# Bash script to convert imgs in subfolders to video (using ffmpeg and Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, bash, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert all files in folders given by

```
 allFolders.txt
> head folderNames.txt
0001 
0002 
0003 
0004 
0005 
...
```

to a video using ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg version 2.2.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers  built on Apr 20 2015 13:38:52 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
configuration: --prefix=/home/myUsername/usr/local --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-pic --enable-shared --enable-libx264 --disable-vaapi
```

According to some answers here on stackoverflow I wrote the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read p; do
    cd "$p"
    ffmpeg -f concat -i "allImgNames.txt" -framerate 30 -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
    cd -
done < folderNames.txt
```

where `allImgNames.txt` is a text file containing all the image names.

The strange thing is that it works for a few videos but for the rest of the filelist it fails saying `allImgNames.txt: No such file or directory`, which is not true. I checked all paths several times. Also I can execute the `ffmpeg ...` command above manually without problems.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong. All file / folder names are normal (no special characters). Maybe I don't understand enough about bash or ffmpeg.

Comment: Any spaces in file or directory names?

Comment: You change directory in the script, so the file `allImgNames.txt` is no longer in the *current* directory. Unless each directory you change to as a separate file with that name?

Comment: nope. What is really strange is that when I put a `echo "$p"` after `cd "$p"` in the example given above, it behaves normally when I comment the `ffmpeg` comment but it as soon as I uncomment again `ffmpeg` even the paths it prints are wrong (missing leading 0's), eg it prints `30` instead of `0030`

Comment: I have a text file with all image filenames in every subdirectory. That's why I can execute the `ffmpeg` command outside my bash script normally

Comment: With that *exact* name? Remember that filenames in POSIX environments (like Linux) is case-sensitive.

Comment: I know. But in my case both the folder names as well as the image names consist only of numbers (folders: `0001`, `0002` ... ; images: `0001.jpg`, `0002.jpg` ...

Comment: I mean the `allImgNames.txt` file, does it really have that casing? In all folders? And it *does* exist in *all* folders? Does it always fail on the same directories? Or seemingly random? Have you tried doing e.g. `ls allImgNames.txt` in the script instead of the `ffmpeg` command? Or instead of changing directory and `ffmpeg`, just do `ls "$p/allImgNames.txt` in the loop, if the files are missing in only some directories that will make it very obvious.

Comment: Yes they all exist and have that exact filename. I also checked your `ls` command. Everything works perfectly, except when I'm trying to call the `ffmpeg` command from that script.

Comment: Yes it does always fail on the same directories, although what is strange is that the folder names in `allFolders.txt` are ordered, but when I execute the script, it seems to process the folder names in a different order 0001, 0003, ...  instead of 0001, 0002 ...

Answer (score 2):

Add some logic in your script to ensure that files/folders exist before something gets executed.  This will help you debug your issues along the way.

If the folder paths are NOT relative, something like this would help

```
while read p; do
    [ -d "$p" ] && cd "$p" || echo "Folder $p not found"
    [ -f "allImgNames.txt" ] && ffmpeg -f concat -i "allImgNames.txt" -framerate 30 -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4 || echo "$p/allImgNames.txt not found"
    [ -d "$p" ] && cd -
done < folderNames.txt
```

Comment: This script always fails already the second folder "Folder not found". It doesn't event print "Folder $p not found" as it should. When I edit your script such that it doesn't `cd $p` and `cd -` it processes a lot of videos (800 of 3000 in total) so there was some improvement but still there seems to be something wrong.

Comment: OK, so the issue is somewhere in the environment. It might be FFMPG playing with the OLDPWD in some way.  So instead of 'cd -', try using the party to the parent folder.  Also, add an echo statement before "CD $p" to print out the variable $p.

Comment: Thanks. Meanwhile I could solve my problem using your answer. As I said above I was removing all `cd $p` and `cd -` statements and call the files from the parent directory instead. Then I added a line that checks whether the output video already exists and then skips that folder. Like that I could execute the same script several times and at the end got all 3000 videos converted. 
I will mention this hack in a answer, however I still consider this problem as unsolved, since it's not clear why ffmpeg arbitrarily fails when used in that bash script, although all paths are correct.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711050/bash-script-for-ffmpeg-conversion-does-not-loop?rq=1) post `ffmpeg` indeed messes up with loops in a batch script. You have to add `-nostdin` as option to the ffmpeg command, otherwise ffmpeg eats some parts of subsequent folder names.
Moreover some video conversion failed due to [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847674/ffmpeg-libx264-height-not-divisible-by-2) in the `libx264` codec.
To repair it just use this option to convert the image to a image with a even height size: `-vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2"`

With some help of Iyad K's answer I could get my problem solved:

Here is a complete solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read p; do
    # Continue if output file already exists
    {
    if [ -f "$p/output.mp4" ]; 
    then
        echo " --> File already exists. Continue ..."
        continue
    else
        echo " --> Start processing vid ..."
    fi
    }    

    # Convert video using ffmpeg:
    # "-nostdin" prevents bashscript from messing up
    # "-vf ..." makes sure the video doesn't break for images with uneven pixel hight
    ffmpeg -f concat -i "$p/allImgNames.txt" -nostdin -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" "$p/output.mp4" 
done < folderNames.txt
```

Some remarks:
Somehow the `ffmpeg` command seems to mess up bash scripts, e.g. some path are not printed correctly anymore, which could cause `cd "$p"` and `cd -` to fail.
What was also strange is the fact that the folders where not processed in the same sequential order given by `folderNames.txt`, but apparantly in some random order.